# Colors in Terminal and VIM with Windows Subsystem

Tags: terminal, vim, colors, vimrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux through the Windows Subsystem, and I thought it was pretty cool. However, I'm having issues setting up colors in my terminal and VIM. I used to use Ubuntu as a thing to play around in, and when I programmed in VIM, there was syntax coloring, line numbers, etc. However, when I run VIM the way I am now in the Windows Subsystem, the text is all black. Is there a way to modify my .VIMRC file to show colors again, or is the lack of color an issue with the Windows Subsystem? Likewise, how can I do the same with my terminal? The colors seem dull and muted, so is there a way to change the color profile in my terminal as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I customized the color on my Windows terminal:

1. Right click on the window, select `Properties`, then select the `colors` tab.
2. Manually change each of the colors to match the color scheme you want. Below is a picture of my configuration.
3. [VimColors](https://vimcolors.com/) is a helpful site to browse color schemes. When you find one you like, you can go ahead and manually set the colors.

The Windows terminal is not as fancy as the one on Ubuntu so more work is required to make it look pretty.

[image]